# WebApi reordering results?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I hav a problem with WebApi and OData. Slowly moving an API over and... now it seems that the framework is reordering the results.

The following code:

```
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 100, MaxTop = 1000, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    [ODataRoute]
    public IEnumerable<Reflexo.Api.GrdJob> Get(ODataQueryOptions options) {
        var nodes = Repository.GrdJob
            .Include(x=>x.Cluster)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => new Reflexo.Api.GrdJob() {
                Id = x.Id,
                Identity = x.Code,
            }).AsQueryable();
        nodes = (IQueryable<Reflexo.Api.GrdJob>)options.ApplyTo(nodes);
        var retval = nodes.ToArray();
        return nodes;
    }
```

is as simlple as it gets. Comparing the results in the debugger with what I can see on the screen calling the method... the results have a different order.

Note that I am comparing the db side id fields (id) of both the JSON I see in a browser and the fields in the array named retval. I have imposed an artificial default order - which also get into the SQL (checked) and array (checked).

Just the JSON shows results in a different order.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question at all, [OData Query Option top Forces Data To Be Sorted By Primary Key](http://peterkellner.net/2010/03/31/odata-wcfdataservice-top-orderby-default-sort/)? Seems there are some behaviors with sort as it relates to passing in `$top=x`.

Comment: Not really. Funny enough I see no sensible order in the result (Which has more fields). And I can see the order in the array that moves out of my function.

Comment: Odd, I'm grasping at straws here but: What about returning it using `AsQueryable()` in stead of `ToArray` (unless it is already `AsQueryable()`, then just comment out the line all together). Other than that you can push the burden of sorting to the client using `$orderby`.

Comment: Already tried (.AsQueryable on the array). And $orderby should order on the server? The main problem is that i can NOT order on the client - not if I am looking for paging at the same moment. I only want to transfer relevant data. OrderBy seems to be totally ignored.

Comment: If you are using EF then the commands sent by oData will create the correct query in EF which the major benifit of using odata. It allows you to expose a DbSet (or filtered DbSet) as IQueryable and the client can pass in $orderby, $filter, etc. Which then translate into EF commands and does server side filtering. By calling ToArray you are removing a major benefit of using oData with EF. (this is response to `And $orderby should order on the server?`)

Comment: @Igor Read my post. I do get the correct ordered data into the array. So, that DOES WORK. The problem is that I get reordered results AFTER the end of the method. The db query is perfectly aligned with what I want.

Comment: As simple as it gets: http://localhost/Reflexo.Server.Api/GrdJob. I do a default ordering in the code (as you can read). The array is properly sorted - just somehow after that I get randomized results.

Comment: Thanks. If you change the code so and the url like this does it have any effect? Code: `return (IQueryable<Reflexo.Api.GrdJob>)options.ApplyTo(nodes);` Url: 
`localhost/Reflexo.Server.Api/GrdJob/?$count=true&$top=50&$skip=0&$orderby=Id desc` - I make the assumption that Id is cased the same way but if you have json case conversion enabled it might be cased as `id`. Also I realize this still does not solve the issue of default sorting but maybe it will point you to why that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware the `EnableQueryAttribute` is going to execute `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo` *again* using a default set of query settings. (See the [`EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery`](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs#L509) method source.) Try removing the attribute.

Comment: Nearly an answer - you are totally right. Is there some sample how to deal with this without EnableQueryAttribute? I am not sure what it does, but if I remove that - i get the expected result. That said, query optins are "Plenty" ;) Implementing them all by hand will be challenging.

Comment: @TomTom - he means just remove that attribute, that's it. You can keep your existing ApplyTo which applies the OData filters, orderby, paging, etc. So keep all things the same, just remove that attribute and no need to do anything "by hand".

Comment: Yes, but it means i have possibly to do a lot of stuff by hand. DEFAULT and max values, for one thing. The attbiute allows me a lot of control that a simply "Apply" does not have.

Comment: @TomTom: `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo` has an overload that takes an `ODataQuerySettings` argument, and the public `ODataQueryOptions.Validate` method takes a `ODataValidationSettings` argument. The query settings and validation settings cover every property you can set on the `EnableQuery` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the other contributors on this post. I ran into the same issue described above, and managed to disable OData's default sorting by adding the `EnsureStableOrdering = false` to my `[EnableQuery()]` attribute.